# Change generic type from within the class

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have this class to generate random objects:

```
public class Generator<T>
{
    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

    public Generator()
    {
        //can't a generic type constraint that says "implements any interface" so I use this ugly thing...
        if (!typeof(T).IsInterface)
            throw new Exception("Generator needs to be instanciated with an interface generic parameter");

        types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))).ToList();
    }

    public T GetRandomObject()
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(types.Count);
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(types[index]);

    }

    public void SetNewGeneric<N>()
    {
        T = N; //this doesn't work...
        types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))).ToList();
    }

}
```

I use it like so:

```
Generator<IEnemy> generator = new Generator<IEnemy>();
var randomEnemy = generator.GetRandomObject(); //create and return randomly, any object that implements IEnemy...
```

My question is, is there any way to change the type of `T` at runtime so I can do something like

```
generator.SetGeneric<IWeapon>();
var weapon = generator.GetRandomObject();
```

Any other ways I could do this if I'm taking the wrong path ?

Thanks.

Comment: Then `generator` is no longer a `Generator<IEnemy>`. How do you expect that to work, and how do you want to use that?

Comment: What about making Generator static and having a Set<T> property return a typed generator.  So you aren't creating an instance of generator with a given type, but can dynamically set the type and then get random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a generic method, but not a generic class:

```
public class Generator
{
    private Random rnd = new Random();

    // Make it so you only have to get the interfaces for a given type once.
    private Dictionary<Type, List<Type>> _typeCache = new Dictionary<Type, List<Type>>();

    public T GetRandomObject<T>()
    {
        List<Type> types = GetTypes<T>();

        int index = rnd.Next(types.Count);
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(types[index]);
    }

    private List<Type> GetTypes<T>()
    {
        List<Type> types;

        if (!_typesCache.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out types))
        {
            //can't a generic type constraint that says "implements any interface" so I use this ugly thing...
            if (!typeof(T).IsInterface)
                throw new Exception("Generator needs to be instanciated with an interface generic parameter");

            types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))).ToList();

            _typesCache[typeof(T)] = types;
        }

        return types;
    }
}
```

Either that or you'll have to just create a different generator for each type if you want to keep the class generic.

Comment: I marked this one for the solution and the typesCache implementation, to keep the code's performances.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this...
You don't need a generic class.
Just make your methods generic.
Basically just combine all your code in one method

```
public class Generator
{
    public static T GetRandomObject<T>()
    {
        if(typeof(T).IsInterface)
            throw new Exception("Generator needs to be instanciated with an interface generic parameter");

        Random rnd = new Random();

        var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))).ToList();
        int index = rnd.Next(types.Count);
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(types[index]);
    }
}
```

Now,if you are worried about performance you could cache the list if types in a
   Dictionary< string,List < Type>>

Answer (score 0):

Or you can generate generators:

```
public class Generator<T>
{
    private readonly Random rnd;
    private List<Type> types = new List<Type>();

    public Generator(Random r)
    {
        rnd = r;

        if (!typeof(T).IsInterface)
            throw new Exception("Generator needs to be instanciated with an interface generic parameter");

        types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))).ToList();
    }

    public T GetRandomObject()
    {
        int index = rnd.Next(types.Count);
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(types[index]);
    }
}

public class MetaGenerator
{
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public Generator<T> Create<T>()
    {
        return new Generator<T>(rnd);
    }
}

var metaGenerator = new MetaGenerator();

var generator = metaGenerator.Create<IEnemy>();
generator = metaGenerator.Create<IWeapon>();
```